# What do you call it when loads of amendments are put forward in order to obstruct a bill?

Tags: word-request

What do you call it when loads of amendments are put forward in order to obstruct a bill? Filibuster? Stonewall? I believe there's a special term for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "amendments to stall bill", I've run into "amendment gridlock".
[thehill.com "Energy bill stalled..."](https://thehill.com/policy/energy-environment/486715-energy-bill-stalled-amid-amendment-gridlock)

"Filibuster" means giving a long speech. "Stonewall" is for any sort of obstruction where the metaphor fits.

Comment: So 'stonewall' fits, doesn't it?

Comment: Not well, I think. It connotes something less active than a flurry of amendments - something more like a stone wall, like ignoring or  refusing to answer or to act in any way.